# Regular expression replace characters with the correct number of spaces

Tags: php, regex

I wanna replace with spaces all characters except number, lecters, space and other characters `#=<>();*,.+\/-`

e.g. `preg_replace("/[^ #=<>();*,.+\/-\w]+/", " ", $string);`

My problem is that when in the `$string` there are two or more consecutive characters to be replaced, the function replace this characters with just one space, while I need that the functions replace the two or more characters with two or more spaces.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If  your character class contains both forward and backward slash, you need to escape both forward and backward slashes which are present inside the character class.

> I wanna replace with spaces all characters except number, lecters, space and other characters `#=<>();*,.+\/-`

- `\w` represent letters,numbers and also `_` symbol. So avoid using `\w` inside the character class.
- As another answer said, you need to remove the `+` after character class, which replaces one or more characters with a single space.
- And your regex should be,

  ```
  [^- #=<>();*,.+\\\/0-9A-Za-z]
  ```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vQ9aU2/1)

- In the demo it matches `_` symbol because it isn't included in the NOT character class. In the replacement part i gave only a single space. It replaces three `_` symbols with three spaces.

Comment: Thanks, this is a better reply.

Answer (score 3):

You should match only one character at a time. You must also escape some of the characters.

Change

```
 preg_replace("/[^ #=<>();*,.+/-\w]+/", " ", $string);
```

to

```
 preg_replace("/[^ #=<>();*,\\.+\\/\\-\\w]/", " ", $string);
```